# How can a sourced bash snippet conditionally provide a function to the sourcing shell?

Tags: bash, include

Is it possible to source a Bash snippet, but only actually provide a function from inside it if a certain condition holds true?

So what I am asking is that I can unconditionally source all files from a directory, but the sourced files contain the logic to provide functions to the sourcing shell or not.

Example:

- `.bashrc` sources whole sub folder `.bashrc.d`
- `.bashrc.d/xyz` provides a function `adduser2group` which works on old systems where `usermod` doesn't handle `-a -G`
- `.bashrc.d/xyz` should provide that function *only* to the sourcing shell *if* it's running on such old system.

My current method is to conditionally create an `alias` named `adduser` after the Debian program (`alias adduser=adduser2group`). So I only implement the `adduser <user> <group>` semantics, but still it's helpful.

Is there a solution that doesn't require this workaround? After all this method means a chance for name clashes which I'd prefer to avoid.

Comment: if you're at all familiar with how `configure` works, it just does 1-time non-destructive tests to determine what environment it's running in, and uses conditional logic to set paths, program names, and params as needed to provide a consistent scripting experinece. Seems like that will work for you too (and that you're almost there anyway). Just my 2cents worth. Good luck.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can define the functions you want and, whenever a particular condition holds, you just unset the function:

```
$ function alpha() { echo $1; }
$ alpha 10
10
```

Evaluating your condition -- and considering it holds true:

```
$ if [[ your condition ]]; then unset alpha; fi
$ alpha 10
alpha: command not found
```

Comment: A lazy approach I've used is to have the function redefine itself the first time it's called. `alpha() { if condition; then alpha() { stuff; }; else alpha() { :; }; fi; alpha; }`

Comment: @kojiro That's very interesting in cases you know the call will be performed and you don't want any errors to come up. Nice solution!

Comment: @Rubens: great answer. Straight to the point. Wasn't aware I could use `unset` this way. Thanks. +1 and I'll accept as soon as that works.

Answer (score 15):

You can use standard shell logic to control whether functions are defined are not.

`lib.sh`:

```
if true; then
    foo() {
        echo foo
    }
else
    bar() {
        echo bar
    }
fi
```

`test`:

```
#!/bin/bash

. ./lib.sh
foo
bar
```

When running it, only `foo` is defined:

```
$ bash test
foo
test: line 5: bar: command not found
```

Substitute `if true` with more appropriate logic for your application…

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative, it appears that `return` also does the job. So one can say:

```
[[ condition ]] || return
```